# linear regression function creating a list instead of a model

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit an lm model using R. However, for some reason this code creates a list of the data instead of the usual regression model.

The code I use is this one
`lm(Soc_vote ~ Inclusivity + Gini + Un_den, data = general_inclusivity_sweden )`

But instead of the usual coefficients, the title of the variable appears mixed with the data in this way:

```
     (Intercept)  Inclusivity0.631  Inclusivity0.681  Inclusivity0.716    Inclusivity0.9  
           35.00             -4.00             -6.74             -4.30              4.90
```

Does anybody know why this happened and how it can be fixed?

Comment: That call doesn't exactly give that result. To get that result, you'd call `coef` (or equivalent) on a model that looks like `lm(y ~ Inclusivity, df)` where `Inclusivity` is character or factor, so the numbers appended are the contrast levels. Also note that that's not a list, it's a numeric vector.

Comment: Perhaps you want `summary(lm(Soc_vote ~ Inclusivity + Gini + Un_den, data = general_inclusivity_sweden))`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is called a `named num` (a numeric vector with names). You can do the following:

```
Model <-  lm(Soc_vote ~ Inclusivity + Gini + Un_den, data = general_inclusivity_sweden) # Assign the model to an object called Model
summary(Model) # Summary table
Model$coefficients # See only the coefficients as a named numeric vector
Model$coefficients[[1]] # See the first coefficient without name
```

If you want *all* the coefficients without names (so just a numeric vector), try:

```
unname(coef(Model))
```

Comment: That's not a list, it's a numeric vector

Comment: Yes, I just updated the answer. Turns out it's a named numeric vector. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you could provide a sample of your data but I'm guessing that the key problem is that the numeric data in `Inclusivity` is stored as a factor. e.g.,

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(incl = as.factor(c(0.631, 0.681, 0.716)), 
                         soc_vote=1:3)
lm(soc_vote ~ incl, x)

Call:
lm(formula = soc_vote ~ incl, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    incl0.681    incl0.716  
          1            1            2
```

Whereas, if you first convert the `Inclusivity` column to double, you get

```
y <- x %>% mutate(incl = as.double(as.character(incl)))
lm(soc_vote ~ incl, y)

Call:
lm(formula = soc_vote ~ incl, data = y)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         incl  
     -13.74        23.29
```

Note that I needed to convert to character first since otherwise I just get the ordinal equivalent of each factor.